# Strong password checker in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/strong-password-checker/) -

> *A password is considered strong if below conditions are all met -*
>
> **1.** *It has at least 6 characters and at most 20 characters.*
>
> **2.** *It must contain at least one lowercase letter, at least one uppercase letter, and at least one digit.*
>
> **3.** *It must **NOT** contain three repeating characters in a row (`...aaa...` is weak, but `...aa...a...` is strong, assuming other
>   conditions are met).*
>
> *Write a function `strong_password_checker(s)`, that takes a string `s`
>   as input, and returns the **MINIMUM** change required to make `s` a
>   strong password. If `s` is already strong, return `0`.*
>
> *Insertion, deletion or replacements of any one character are all
>   considered as one change.*

Here is my solution to this challenge -

> ```
> def strong_password_checker(s: str) -> int:
>     def has_lower(s):
>         for c in s:
>             if c.islower(): return 1
>         return 0
>
>     def has_upper(s):
>         for c in s:
>             if c.isupper(): return 1
>         return 0
>
>     def has_digits(s):
>         for c in s:
>             if c.isnumeric(): return 1
>         return 0
>
>     def find_repeats(s):
>         i = 0
>         j = 0
>         repeats = []
>         while i < len(s) - 1:
>             if s[i+1] == s[i]:
>                 i += 1
>                 continue
>             if (i - j + 1) > 2: repeats.append(i - j + 1)
>             i += 1
>             j = i
>         if (i - j + 1) > 2: repeats.append(i - j + 1)
>         return repeats
>
>     def repeats_after_delete(reps, d):
>         if d >= sum([r - 2 for r in reps]):
>             return []
>         reps = sorted(reps, key=lambda d: d%3)
>         while d > 0:
>             for i in range(len(reps)):
>                 if reps[i] < 3:
>                     continue
>                 r = reps[i] % 3 + 1
>                 reps[i] -= min(r, d)
>                 d -= r
>                 if d <= 0:
>                     break
>         return [r for r in reps if r > 2]
>
>     def num_repeats_change(repeats):
>         return sum([r // 3 for r in repeats])
>
>     total_changes = 0
>     format_changes = (1 - has_lower(s)) + (1 - has_upper(s)) + (1 - has_digits(s))
>     repeats = find_repeats(s)
>     if len(s) < 6:
>         repeat_change = num_repeats_change(repeats)
>         total_changes = max([6 - len(s), format_changes, repeat_change])
>     elif len(s) > 20:
>         repeats = repeats_after_delete(repeats, len(s) - 20)
>         repeat_change = num_repeats_change(repeats)
>         total_changes = len(s) - 20 + max([repeat_change, format_changes])
>     else: 
>         repeat_change = num_repeats_change(repeats)
>         total_changes = max([repeat_change, format_changes])
>     return total_changes
> ```

Here are some example outputs -

```
#print(strongPasswordChecker("aaaaaaaaaaaaAsaxqwd1aaa"))

>>> 6

#Explanation - aa1aa1aa1aAsaxqwd1aa (just an example - delete three characters, add three digits to replace consecutive a's)
```

---

```
#print(strongPasswordChecker("aaaaa"))

>>> 2

#Explanation - aaAaa1 (just an example - add a character (so the length is at least 6), add an uppercase letter to replace consecutive a's)
```

---

```
#print(strongPasswordChecker("aAsaxqwd2aa"))

>>> 0

#Explanation - A strong password (all conditions are met)
```

---

Here are the times taken for each output -

```
%timeit strongPasswordChecker("aaaaaaaaaaaaAsaxqwd1aaa")
>>> 18.7 µs ± 1.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit strongPasswordChecker("aaaaa")
>>> 5.05 µs ± 594 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit strongPasswordChecker("aAsaxqwd2aa")
>>> 7.19 µs ± 469 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It really is too bad they called this a *strong* password checker. It might've been in the 80's, but certainly not anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it shorter:
use any and int: for example:

```
password_contains_digits = int(any(c.isdigit() for c in s))
```

or use set:

```
password_set = set(s)
digits = set("1234567890")
password_contains_digits = int(len(password_set & digits) != 0)
```

or use RegEx:

```
password_contains_digits = len(re.findall(r'[0-9]', s)) != 0
```

Also, regex can help you to find repeating symbols :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use this code for checking whether it has an uppercase/lowercase:

```py
if s.lower() == s:
    # doesn't have any uppercase
if s.upper() == s:
    # doesn't have any lowercase
```

This way, you don't have to iterate through the entire string.